# totaled 969 in the 2014 fiscal year, up 34 percent from 2012 -- comprehension

Tags: grammar, comprehension

Source: http://news.yahoo.com/scores-russian-gays-seeking-asylum-us-060357416.html

> There are no firm statistics on the number of gay Russian asylum seekers. U.S. government agencies that handle applications do not report such details. However, the Department of Homeland Security's latest figures show that **overall applications for asylum by Russians totaled 969 in the 2014 fiscal year, up 34 percent from 2012**.

The subject of that last clause is obviously ***overall applications for asylum by Russians***. ***totaled*** is the verb and ***969 in the 2014 fiscal year*** is the object of the verb with some additional information provided. Only this much I get, but I don't understand how ***up 34 percent from 2012*** fits into the picture. Please help.

Comment: 969 is 34% more than the number of applications in 2012 - apparently there were 723 (969/1.34) in that year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"up 34 percent from 2012" is a prepositional phrase modifying "969".

We can infer that there were about 723 applications during the 2012 fiscal year.